# Proving a recurrence's $\Theta$ with induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, induction, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

> Prove with induction that $T(n)=T(\frac n 2)+\log n = \Theta (n^2)$

Starting with the big $O$, the basis $T(2)\le c 2^2$ is obvious.

Assume it's true for $n$ and prove for $n+1$: $T(n)=T(\frac n 2)+\log n \overset{I.H}\le c (\frac n 2 )^2+ \log n \le c \frac {n^2} 4 + \frac {3n^2} 4 =cn^2$

But I didn't reach an expression with a $"n+1"$, so is it still okay?

Comment: You can show by substitution that $T(n)\sim(\frac 1 2\log^2n)$

Comment: I don't think I understand what do you mean. @A.S.

Comment: $f\sim g$ means that $\lim f/g=1$.

Comment: OK but how can I use that with the induction? also what is $f$ in this case? $n^2$? @A.S.

Comment: I see no reason to use induction. Define $S(n)=T(n)/(1/2\log^2 n)$, write down recursion for $S(n)$ and show that $S(n)\to 1$. Note that $\log$ is base $2$.